# What's more secure from outside hacking - Standalone vs. PC-Based DVRs

Tags: cctv

I'm thinking of installing a few cameras around the house. My main concern is how easy it seems to be to gain access to a internet connected standalone DVR. So still lacking much knowledge I was wondering if PC-based DVRs are more secure when it comes to outside hacking - i.e. via internet or do they use the same software/hardware so it makes no difference?

Comment: *"lacking much knowledge"* - in this case a self-made PC based DVR is probably as insecure as a cheap standalone DVR. The best would be not to internet connect these at all. But, there are actually differences in security between the various systems but this is not standalone vs. PC-based. You can have secure standalone DVR and you insecure PC based solutions and the other way.

Comment: So which one would be easier to secure, as the whole point would be for me to be able to monitor while I'm away.

Comment: If you have the knowledge a self-made system would be easier to secure since you are able to adjust the software and OS as you need contrary to a closed standalone DVR. But, if you don't have the knowledge this will not help and you will be unable to secure any of these. In this case it might be better to buy a standalone device which you don't need to secure in the first place. Using a vendor with a high reputation regarding security might be a good starting point in doing this.

Comment: Do you require access to the cameras from the internet? Because if you don't, just don't connect them to the internet. And if you do need access, I'd suggest you assume that sooner or later an outsider might get to see at least some of the videostreams, so it would be smart to place the cameras so they minimize the privacy issues, and turn them off while you don't need them (e.g. when someone's home).

Comment: @Pascal - that's exactly how I intend to use them - only while I'm away, hence the internet access. I do understand that if someone really wants to gather access they will. My main concern was to not make it easy for casual hackers and bots to (randomly) gain access.